# Como separar em x e y sendo todos menos o ultimo x e o ultimo y?

Tags: python, funções

Estou fazendo uma função para generalizar um train_test_split, e para isso desejo separa dentro da função o X e o y. Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
python
def split(dados):
    SEED = 42367
    X = dados[["NU_NOTA_MT", "NU_NOTA_LC"]]
    y = dados["nota_total"]
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=SEED)
    return train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y
```

Note que quando eu defino o X e o y preciso passar o nome das variáveis dentro da função... Tem como eu passando apenas os dados ele entender que todas -1 é X e a ultima é o y?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o nome das colunas como uma lista e fazer um fatiamento:

```
def split(dados):
    SEED = 42367
    X = dados[dados.columns.to_list()[:-1]]
    y = dados[dados.columns.to_list()[-1:]]
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=SEED)
    return train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y
```